# Is there a way to scale data around a value in python?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas, data-preprocessing

I'm trying to think of a way to scale my data in python around the number 2.
I would need something like a MinMaxScaler, where 2 is the maximum that's scaled to 1, but with the possibility of going over 2. I'm not sure how to approach this, I'm open to any solutions, as I couldn't come up with anything useful.

So let's say I would have these as inputs:
a = [0, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]

and I would get these values back
scaled = [-1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0]

Thank you

Comment: what would be the desired result for ```[0, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 5]```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your desired result, I guess you want code like this:

```py
scaled = [1 - abs(item - 2) for item in a]
```

Could that be it?